# Adding Video to UIActivityViewController IOS7

Tags: ios7, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

PLEASE! This has been driving me crazy for hours. I know its possible to share video to Facebook,twitter ... through UIActivityViewController. PLEASE somebody tell me how to do it!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use the ALAsset object and pass it in:

```
ALAsset * asset = [[ALAsset alloc] init];
[asset setVideoAtPath:urlToVideoFile completionBlock:NULL];
NSArray * activityItems = @[asset];
UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:NULL];
```

Comment: This only enables air drop

Comment: This didn't work at all. I had Fb video share working, was only trying to fix it for Twitter but Fb also stopped working after adding this code...